# Cómo esperar a que se realice una promesa dentro de una función para retornar un valor

Tags: nodejs

Buenas, tengo una función en un módulo en Nodejs, dentro de esa función tengo un Promise, quiero que esa función me retorne un valor después de que se cumpla el Promise, cómo hago para colocar el return dentro del then:

```
app.post("/valuser",function(req,res){
  var Prueba = Modulos.BuscarUser(req.body);
  console.log(Prueba);  
});
```

El módulo:

```
module.exports = {

BuscarUser: function(req){

      var User = require("./mod/User");

      function Buscar_User(){
          return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

          User.findOne({Nombre: req.name}).exec(function (err,docs){    
             if(err){return reject(err);}
             console.log("Linea 1:"+docs.Nombre);
             resolve();
          });

          });

      }

      Buscar_User().then(() => { console.log('Linea 2'); });

      var Test = "Linea 3";          

return Test;
},

RegistrarUser: function(req){ ... }
```

};

La salida de este código sería:

Linea 3

Linea 1 Anderson Campos

Linea 2

Quiero que el "return" se ejecute cuando se cumpla el "then" o dentro del "then" para que la salida pueda ser:

Linea 1 Anderson Campos

Linea 2

Linea 3

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es medio anidado pero creo que la forma seria devolver otra promesa, dejándolo como tu lo hiciste seria así:

```
module.exports = {

BuscarUser: function(req) {
    var User = require("./mod/User");

    function Buscar_User() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            User.findOne({
                Nombre: req.name
            }).exec(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                console.log("Linea 1:" + docs.Nombre);
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        Buscar_User().then(function() {
            console.log('Linea 2');
            var Test = "Linea 3";
            res(Test);
        });
    });
 },

 RegistrarUser: function(req) {...
 }
```

};

Igualmente para mi podrías no usar la función Buscar_User() dentro de BuscarUser y devolver una promesa ejecutando lo que necesites dentro del callback del find. Luego enviar el resolve con los datos que necesites que incluso pueden ser los 3.

```
module.exports = {
BuscarUser: function(req) {
    var User = require("./mod/User");

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        User.findOne({
            Nombre: req.name
        }).exec(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log("Linea 1:" + docs.Nombre);
            console.log('Linea 2');
            var Test = "Linea 3";
            resolve(Test);
        });
    });
},

RegistrarUser: function(req) {...
}
```

};

si solo usas la función Buscar_User una vez no se justifica declararla.